# how to convert XMLGregorianCalender and keep the same date

Tags: java, datetime

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                    .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2015-01-14T00:00:00Z");

new Timestamp(xgcal.toGregorianCalendar().getTime().getTime())
```

Is printing `2015-01-13 19:00:00.0`, how do I keep the exact date time here?

Answer (score 1):

The Timestamp.toString method will print the absolute point in time in the local time zone of the jvm. The xml string you are showing is in UTC. So that is printing the same absolute point in time (assuming your time zone is UTC-5).

If you are interacting with JDBC and you want to insert the date into the database in the UTC time zone, you must provide a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) with the [TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeZone-java.util.TimeZone-) of UTC on your [setTimestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-java.util.Calendar-) and [getTimestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp-int-java.util.Calendar-) calls.

Comment: yes i am trying to insert into the database and its going wrong, any examples you could provide for above

Comment: But what do you mean it is "going wrong"? It seems like the issue you are having here is timezone representation of the same point in time. What time zone do you want all of the data in your database stored in?

Comment: the db timezone is -05:00 and i need to take care of day light savings also

Comment: Is it UTC-0500 or is it America/New_York? These are 2 different things (UTC-0500 does not have daylight savings, America/New_York does).   What do you mean by "take care of day light savings"?